# :before and :after not showing when site is pushed

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to use :before and :after elements to spice up my page, but when I push it, the live site does not have them. On my local computer, both :before and :after is showing up correctly. My live site is here: https://findingfutures.eu

I am using Netlify and Github to push my site. I have tried adding the code to a codepen, and the elements are being displayed correctly there: https://codepen.io/Barsnes/pen/pKBzrK

Here is my code, with a lot of removed content to make it simpler,

```css
.products_design:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: .3em;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  top: -16.5em;
  margin-left: 15%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000040;
}

.products_design:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: .3em;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  bottom: -10.5em;
  margin-left: 15%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000040;
}

.products_design {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 25em 10vw 10em 10vw;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #00000030;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #23232320, #23232305);
}

.products_design h1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  line-height: .8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #00000060;
}

.products_design span {
  display: block;
}

.products_design img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.project_1,
.project_2,
.project_3,
.project_4,
.project_5,
.project_6 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.products_design h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding: .4em .4em 0 .2em;
}

.products_design p {
  padding: .4em .4em 2em .4em;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.products_design a {
  display: block;
  color: orange;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.products_design a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<div class="products_design">

  <div class="products">
    <div class="products_title">
      <h1>our past<span>projects</span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="project_1">

    <img src="images/projects/project__tobias_barsnes_website.png" />
    <h2>Portfolio Website</h2>
    <p>Lorem<a href="https://www.barsnes.tk">Click to view project</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="project_2">
    <img src="images/projects/project__portrait_photography.png">
    <h2>Portrait Photography</h2>
    <p>Lorem<a href="projects/portraits">Click to view project</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="project_3">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?photoshop">
    <h2>Design</h2>
    <p>Lorem<a href="https://www.barsnes.tk">Click to view project</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe try use `px` instead `em`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before <-- css3 is now ::before, in css2 it was :before

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue, a hard refresh (CTRL + F5) should be your first port of call.

Comment: I tried changing em to px, not result. 
I changed :before to ::before, no result.
I did a hard refresh, no result.

Comment: The pseudo element is nowhere to be found in DOM inspector when viewing your live site, so the only logical conclusion is that you messed something up while deploying this … Your stylesheet has a rule selecting `.design_title` right before the `.products_design` rule you have shown above.

Comment: Yeah, the pseudo element is nowhere to be found in your CSS https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/css/e47fac4d1be5d9c2e887dba0faa3ac52dda2a3c5/style.css

Comment: @CBroe I have no idea what I could have messes up tough. I code it in atom, check my browser for the changes. Then I use Github Desktop to push it, and then  Netlify atomatically deploys the site for me.

Comment: Well maybe you overlooked an error message while doing so, or forgot to explicitly clear some cache somewhere (if required.) Fact is, what you have shown above is not part of the styles of your live site, so you can stop looking for reasons elsewhere. You didn’t _successfully_ deploy what you think you did, so go and find out why.

Comment: @CBroe I will try to find the error, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo elements does not work well with @import, and can therefor cause problems in the browser.

If you move all your ::before and ::after to the main css wihtout using @import, it should work perfectly.

**Correct Example Code**

```
@import url("_styles/header.css");
@import url("_styles/body.css");
.products_design::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  top: -16.5em;
  margin-left: 15%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000040;
}

.products_design::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  bottom: -10.5em;
  margin-left: 15%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000040;
}

.about_images::before {
  content:" ";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000040
}
```

**Wrong Example Code**

```
@import url("_styles/media_query.css");
@import url("_styles/cookie.css");
@import url("_styles/pseudeo_elements.css");
```

Answer (score -1):

It's `::before` and `::after`.
For some environments selectors may work with a single `:`, but it's not the proper syntax in CSS3.

Update:
`:before` and `::before` will both work, as CSS3 is backwards compatible with CSS2, as [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) pointed out.

Comment: When I first started playing with them, I used ::before and ::after , but the same problem occured so i tried :before and :after

Comment: Well, that's strang. It works for me. Probably something client-side?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before#Syntax: _“CSS3 introduced the ::before notation (with two colons) to distinguish pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept :before, introduced in CSS2.”_ - I think you’d be very hard pressed to find one for which the latter would not be true. The web doesn’t usually break backwards compatibility, let alone for inanities like this …

Comment: @SvenBoekelder Seems strange, my first tought aswell, but I tried Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox and Opera, still nothing that showed up :/

Comment: @TobiasBarsnes I think it will be hard for anyone to help without being able to reproduce the same matter :/